# How To Get Data From A Custom Event In Magento

Tags: magento

I have an observer module that I have written for Magento. It simply monitors an event called `mgd_order_prep` which is triggered by a custom dispatcher like this:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent("mgd_order_prep", array('orderdata' => $order));
```

$order is simply a magento `sales/order` object.

My event fires and my function in the proper class executes:

```
function updateOrderPrepPDF($observer)
{
    Mage::log("Update Order Prep",null,'orderprep.log');
    Mage::log($observer->getOrderdata(),null,'orderprep.log');
}
```

I see what I should after the first log event, but I dont see ANYTHING for when I try to output the order data (it outputs blank - or null).

How do I get the data I pass in at the dispatch event out at the execution point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly get Data using `getData()` method :

```
function updateOrderPrepPDF($observer)
{
   Mage::log(print_r($observer->getData(),true),null,'orderprep.log');
}
```

Check this log inside `var/log` directory.

Try this code and let me know if you still have any query.